# Figuring out dates based on a set period of time

Tags: php, date, timestamp

I have MySQL column for start date(timestamp) and end date(timestamp) and 3rd column of paying_period (3 months or 6 months) i want to get 3 month(paying_period) difference in full period.

**Example** start date is `1-jan-2012` and end date is `1-jan-2013`. I want 3 month period in that`, like 1st installment goes on`1-mar-2012`,2nd on`1-june-2012` and so on.

How can i do it?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) makes working with dates easy

```
$date = new DateTime('1-jan-2012'); // Start date
$date->modify('+3 months');         // 3 months later
echo $date->getTimestamp();         // timestamp
$date->modify('+3 months');         // 6 mnths later
echo $date->getTimestamp();         // timestamp
$date->modify('+3 months');         // 9 months later
echo $date->getTimestamp();         // timestamp
```